# Problem with implementing hivemall regression function

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Hello when attempting to use hive-malls regression tool kit I run into errors when attempting to build the feature representation.

I've been following this guide https://hivemall.incubator.apache.org/userguide/supervised_learning/tutorial.html and have been attempting to reproduce it. I've used the code provided however I'm running into issues when running.

My issue seems to be with this part of the guide

```
create table if not exists purchase_history as
select 1 as id, "Saturday" as day_of_week, "male" as gender, 600 as price, "book" as category, 1 as label
union all
select 2 as id, "Friday" as day_of_week, "female" as gender, 4800 as price, "sports" as category, 0 as label
union all
select 3 as id, "Friday" as day_of_week, "other" as gender, 18000 as price, "entertainment" as category, 0 as label
union all
select 4 as id, "Thursday" as day_of_week, "male" as gender, 200 as price, "food" as category, 0 as label
union all
select 5 as id, "Wednesday" as day_of_week, "female" as gender, 1000 as price, "electronics" as category, 1 as label
;

create table if not exists training as
select
id,
array_concat( – concatenate two arrays of quantitative and categorical features into single array
quantitative_features(
array("price"), – quantitative feature names
price – corresponding column names
),
categorical_features(
array("day of week", "gender", "category"), – categorical feature names
day_of_week, gender, category – corresponding column names
)
) as features,
label
from
purchase_history
;
```

This is copied straight from the guide. https://hivemall.incubator.apache.org/userguide/supervised_learning/tutorial.html

When running I am getting this error

```
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapRunner.run(ExecMapRunner.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating id
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorSelectOperator.process(VectorSelectOperator.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.vectorForward(Operator.java:966)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:939)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.closeOp(VectorMapOperator.java:990)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:193)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException: argument must be a constant value: array<string>
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.udf.VectorUDFAdaptor.evaluate(VectorUDFAdaptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.expressions.VectorExpression.evaluateChildren(VectorExpression.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.udf.VectorUDFAdaptor.evaluate(VectorUDFAdaptor.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorSelectOperator.process(VectorSelectOperator.java:146)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException: argument must be a constant value: array<string>
    at hivemall.utils.hadoop.HiveUtils.getConstStringArray(HiveUtils.java:502)
    at hivemall.ftvec.trans.QuantitativeFeaturesUDF.initialize(QuantitativeFeaturesUDF.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.udf.VectorUDFAdaptor.init(VectorUDFAdaptor.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.udf.VectorUDFAdaptor.evaluate(VectorUDFAdaptor.java:104)
    ... 18 more
```

However when I run the same query alone, without creating a table, I get the right results.

```
1    "price:600.0","day of week#Saturday","gender#male","category#book"    1
2    "price:4800.0","day of week#Friday","gender#female","category#sports"0
3    "price:18000.0","day of week#Friday","gender#other","category#entertainment"    0
4    "price:200.0","day of week#Thursday","gender#male","category#food"    0
5    "price:1000.0","day of week#Wednesday","gender#female","category#electronics"    1
```

Any idea why I am not able to save this information in a table?

Comment: Judging from your error message you have vectorization enabled, try to turn it off with `set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = false;`.

Comment: @serge_k Hi. Thank You very much that solved the issue. Do you have any idea why that would cause a problem? Either way you should re-post the comment as an answer so I can upvote it

Comment: It probably has something to do with Hivemall's implementation, vectorized UDF in Hive is not a trivial thing that's why it's better to turn it off for third-party UDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create table without union all:

```
create table if not exists purchase_history as

select id,day_of_week,gender,price,category,label
from
(
select stack(5,
1, "Saturday" , "male"   , 600  , "book"          , 1,
2, "Friday"   , "female" , 4800 , "sports"        , 0,
3, "Friday"   , "other"  , 18000, "entertainment" , 0,
4, "Thursday" , "male"   , 200  , "food"          , 0,
5, "Wednesday", "female" , 1000 , "electronics"   , 1
) as ( id,day_of_week,gender,price,category,label)
)s;
```

Comment: Hi. I attempted to use this instead but I think there is a syntax error. It looks right to me but I'm getting an error

Comment: FAILED: ParseException line 6:0 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'stack' '(' in join source

Comment: @VenomSnake14 Forgot to add alias at the end. fixed

Comment: That fixed the issue with your suggestion however I'm still having the same error as before. I believe it's coming from the part where I attempt to create the training table

Comment: @VenomSnake14 You said "However when I run the same query alone, without creating a table, I get the right results."  Try to localize what causing error exactly

Comment: The Error seems to come from hivemalls HiveUtil.java more specifically this section

Comment: if (!ObjectInspectorUtils.isConstantObjectInspector(oi)) {
            throw new UDFArgumentException("argument must be a constant value: "
                    + TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfoFromObjectInspector(oi));
        }

Comment: the error is weird... and it is not related to create table. My first hypothesis that it is subfolders created by union all was wrong then